# sscanf in C. Separating unknown number of doubles on a line to an array

Tags: c, type-conversion, scanf

I there are similar questions out there, but none of that did really help me with my problem.
I get a string with unknown number of floating point numbers and I have to cut them seperatly to an array.

What I've got is:

```
   h=0;
   while(fstring[h]!='\n'){  //So first I count how many spaces there are in the string
            if(fstring[h]==' '){
                sc++;
            }
            h++;
    }
    vars=sc;
    for(h=0;h<vars;h++){
        sscanf(fstring,"%lf",&scanned);
        matrix[h]=scanned;
    }
```

So why does this not work? It throws an error every time..

Comment: Wait, it suddenly started to work.. I sorry for posting weird question, but computers sometimes just act weird..

Comment: What is ASCII 10? Shouldn't it be 0?

Comment: The code you've posted will keep scanning the first number repeatedly.

Comment: The `10` would be better written `'\n'`...

Comment: Martin Broadhurst: exactly :) ...so how should I change it? I mean still using sscanf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    double fmatrix[100] = { 0 };
    double *matrix = fmatrix;
    double scanned;
    int bytesread;
    char string[100];
    char *fstring = string;
    int i;

    fgets ( string, 99, stdin );
    fstring = string;

    while ( sscanf ( fstring, "%lf%n", &scanned, &bytesread ) > 0 )
    {
        fstring += bytesread;
        *matrix++ = scanned;
    }

    matrix = fmatrix;

    for ( i = 0; i < 50; i++ )
    {
        printf ( "%lf\n", *matrix++ );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to have both `char string[100];` and `char *fstring = string;`?

Comment: You can't do pointer increments on `string` as it's not a pointer. You can change the content of `string` but not where it's allocated.

Comment: I tried this using only <code>fstring</code> but it didn't work. Could you explain exactly what happens if you just use the pointer to get the input? Thanks.

Comment: You need to allocate the memory to read to, you could do that on the stack by using `char string[100];` or on the heap by using `malloc()`. If you don't and/or you don't initialize `fstring` the code will, if you're lucky crash.

Comment: Even if you can get away by using only `fstring` it's good practice to keep the address to what you've allocated on the heap and not manipulate that pointer, otherwise you don't know what to `free()`.

Comment: See my answer that uses this code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37761106/2773311). When I tried using malloc to create the pointer and skipping the char array part, only the first 3 numbers were parsed.

Comment: Well, you should basically be able to replace `char string[100];` with `char *string = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));`. Be sure to check `string` so that it's not `NULL`, although with modern operating systems that seldom happens. Also, don't forget to `free(string);` before exiting. `sizeof(char)` may be redundant, but it doesn't add any overlay and it's good practice. If this is what you did, I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Didn't you say that you needed to keep the original address of the pointer though? If I only have a single pointer, will moving the pointer (as in changing where it points to) cause memory leaks when it's freed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115096/discussion-between-onemasse-and-arc676).

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend the use of `strtod` rather than `sscanf` here.  Something like this should work:

```
char *ptr, *endptr = fstring;
int h = 0;
do {
    ptr = endptr;
    matrix[h++] = strtod(ptr, &endptr);
} while (endptr != ptr && isspace(*endptr) && *endptr != '\n');
```

Memory allocation and recovery from ill-formed input left as an exercise.

Comment: This works perfectly.Thank you! The only problem is I don't understand that code:) Could explain how it works, on a really fundamental level?

Comment: I have one of these problems with this code:      Segmentation fault/Bus error/Memory limit exceeded/Stack limit exceeded  .  Is there some problem with memory allocation? I only need 20 numbers max, so the string should be less than 20 times 8 (number of digits) plus 19 spaces, can I restrict that?

Comment: Here's an explanation of strtod: http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod  If that's not the part that doesn't make sense, please be more specific about what you don't understand.  Meantime, *I* don't understand how you can be uncertain about *which* error you're getting -- you listed four entirely different things -- but yeah, you're probably running off the end of your array.  For help with that, I recommend you post a new question with a complete test case that folks can compile and watch crash.

Comment: Make sure your string is null terminated. Normal strings should be but if you've received this in a message like I did you might be dealing with an array of chars and strtod merrily ploughs through your RAM doing its best.